# What's the best way to add git repositories as models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I would like to create a project management app in rails that includes the ability to upload git repositories. I'm unclear what means to use as the upload, as it seems PaperClip and ActiveStorage do not allow for selecting directories as uploads(gits are essentially directories, right?). I want to have my Project model contain multiple repositories
Part B: 
Should I save the repository locally or in a database with blobs? Are both of these options feasible?

Comment: What do you mean "upload git repositories"?

Comment: So you can upload or "push" them to my own server, instead of e.g github

Comment: You want to push them to your rails server? Or, your own git server? If the former, do you want to interact with them once they're on the server? Or, are they just a sort of "archive"?

Comment: push onto my server, but also be able to use them as models. Maybe have the push be automated by a folder upload of the git

Answer (score 0):

Git itself can be used to handle pushing gits to your server:

https://dev.to/erhankilic/setting-up-your-own-git-server--26h6

Handling gits as ruby models can be done with [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) gem

Then you will need [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) to create a model whenever a git file within that folder is modified

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does that gem answer the OP's question?

Comment: The gem allows you to manipulate git repositories, but it doesn't provide a simple means of uploading them in a web app.
I'm looking to be able to upload git repositories to a rails server and then be able to view/manipulate them on the interface I create. The gem would work for the viewing park, which I can do. The only file upload gems I have found seem to only work with single files, not folders.

Comment: You don't need to use ruby to upload gits. [Git itself can handle it](https://dev.to/erhankilic/setting-up-your-own-git-server--26h6) (although you will still need interface to create repositories)

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't provide a way to add git repositories as models, to make them manipulable on my app.

Comment: You can track the git directory with [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen), and create a model whenever a new directory is created

Comment: Thanks - So if I create a git repository inside the public folder of my rails app- and start the server, push a git- rails will automatically allow this to happen? I'm kind of new to this but I don't think rails is a file server like that out of the box. Do I create a route for this?